# Is Ripple Labs Inc. subject to US sanctions against Russia?

Tags: sanctions

To the best of my understanding the answer is no because they are a technology company and not a financial institution. However because their consensus based technology is distributed on the systems of financial institutions which are subject to prohibitions by sanctions I would think prohibitions would apply to Ripple and their products. I'm going off of [this document](https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/126/correspondent_accounts_directive_2.pdf) when I refer to "sanctions". And have learned what I know about [Ripple](https://ripple.com/) Primarily from [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/ripple-cryptocurrency.asp).